# Safari extension service worker not sending cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-web-extension

I have a Chrome extension which is working correctly in Chrome. When converting it to a Safari extension, I've run into an issue.

When the user first opens the extension popup, the extension opens a new tab where the user needs to sign in. After signing in, the user has a cookie with a session token. The issue is that when I make a POST request using `fetch` from the extension service worker, it doesn't send the cookie.

It does work when I disable the "Prevent cross-site tracking" checkbox in Safari preferences, but we can't ask users to do that.

It also works when I send the request from a script in the extension popup, but I need to make periodic requests in the background, without user interaction.

Is there documentation that explains this behavior? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Safari.